# How can I automaticly read values on PySimpleGui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I have added a browse folder button but it not gives me values until I click another button.

I tried reading it like this

```
while True:
   event, values = mainwindow.Read()
   if values['Select folder...'] != '':
      print(values['Select folder...'])
```

but the same thing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No layout shown in your issue.

For example, you use `sg.FolderBrowse` here.

The option `target` is default as `(sg.ThisRow, -1)`, means element just before your `sg.FolderBrowse` at same row.

If there's no target in your layout, no event will be generated.
If there's target, event of target will be generated only when target with option `enable_events=True`.

So, you should have a target element in your layout, most of time, it is `sg.InputText` with option `enable_events=True`.

[image: Window]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.InputText(enable_events=True), sg.FolderBrowse('Select folder...')],
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)
    if values['Select folder...'] != '':
        print(values['Select folder...'])

window.close()
```

```
0 {0: 'D:/Document', 'Select folder...': 'D:/Document'}
D:/Document
```

There'll be problem if any event generated from `sg.InputText`, like key 'A' pressed. That's not the event you need, and maybe neither element `sg.InputText`. So next example shown only `sg.FolderBrowse`.

[image: Window]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.InputText(disabled=True, visible=False, enable_events=True), sg.FolderBrowse('Select folder...')],
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)
    if values['Select folder...'] != '':
        print(values['Select folder...'])

window.close()
```

```
0 {0: 'D:/Document', 'Select folder...': 'D:/Document'}
D:/Document
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I will try this. And sorry about not sharing all code with layouts. Because my code is soo long for posting like this.